# Fill in the blank

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm having a problem replacing my String.

This is the Question class method.

```
public class Question
{
private String text;
private String answer;

/**
Constructs a question with empty question and answer.
 */
public Question(String qText) 
{
    text = qText;
    answer = "";
}

/**
Sets the answer for this question.
@param correctResponse the answer
 */
public void setAnswer(String correctResponse)
{
    answer = correctResponse;
}

/**
Checks a given response for correctness.
@param response the response to check
@return true if the response was correct, false otherwise
 */
public boolean checkAnswer(String response)
{
    return response.equals(answer);
}

/**
Displays this question.
 */
public void display()
{
    System.out.println(text);
}
}
```

And this is my method

```
This is my blankQuestions class

import java.util.ArrayList;  


public class BlankQuestion extends Question {  

public BlankQuestion(String qText) {   
    return qText.replaceAll("_+\\d+_+", "_____");


    String tempSplit[] = questionText.split("_");  
    setAnswer(tempSplit[1]);  

}  
public void setAnswer(String correctChoice){  
    super.setAnswer( correctChoice );  

}  

@Override  
public boolean checkAnswer (String response){  
    return super.checkAnswer(response);  

}  

public String toString(){  
    return super.toString();  
}  


}
```

This is my main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class QuestionDemo  
{  
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
  Question[] quiz = new Question[2];  

  BlankQuestion question0 = new BlankQuestion(  
     "2 + 2 = _4_");  
  quiz[0] = question0;  

  BlankQuestion question1 = new BlankQuestion(  
     "The color of the sky is _blue_.");  
  quiz[1] = question1;  

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
  for (Question q : quiz)  
  {  
     q.display();  
     System.out.println("Your answer: ");  
     String response = in.nextLine();  
     System.out.println(q.checkAnswer(response));  
  }  
}  
}
```

From what I understand, I'm replace [underscore]4[underscore] with 5x[underscore], this is similar to filling in the blank, I store the 4. and replace the part of the string with ***_*__*_*_**. Unfortado, that is my result. I think my logic is right, but I have no idea why my return is not what I expected.

Comment: What are you trying to replace?

Comment: _4_ with _____ just that part of the string

Comment: You're returning `temp`, which has not being modified...`temp` in, `temp` out, no change....

Comment: Would my return be temp3 then?

Comment: @Michael You could (`return temp3`), but I don't see if actually fixing the problem, as it's unlikely to have replaced anything...

Answer (score 2):

Just do it all at once:

```
return qText.replaceAll("_+\\d+_+", "_____");
```

It replaces one or more underscores followed by one or more digits followed by one or more underscores with five underscores.

Comment: This doesn't work, I understand what you're doing though. It just doesn't return correctly, maybe it's something else that I'm doing incorrectly...

Comment: What are you returning? `.replaceAll` doesn't modify the original string.

Comment: I'm returning temp, but earlier madprogrammer said my return was wrong, so i'm trying to figure that out now.

Comment: @Michael: You can skip the temporary variable and just `return` the resulting string.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense but it's not return correctly still hmm. Maybe it has something to do with overriding.

Comment: I edited the post and it has all my classes. I'm pretty sure that posting all these codes up and having people look at it is wrong by the Stack rules... is it?

Comment: @Michael: There's nothing wrong with it. Your `return` statement immediately exits the function, so the code after it doesn't run.

Comment: That is true.. I'm going to have to keep fiddling with this then. I'll probably have to add another method to store the answer.